# Validar la fecha de un datetimepicker para que solo acepte el ultimo dia de cada mes

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datetimepicker

me gustaría saber como puedo validar la fecha de un datetimepicker en c# windowsform,
el sistema trata sobre una depreciación de activos, pero solo quiero que permita hacer la depreciación el ultimo día del mes.
El formulario solo cuenta con un datetimepicker y un boton.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime PrimerDiaMes = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
        DateTime UltimoDiaMes = PrimerDiaMes.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (FinMesDateTimePicker.Value.Date == UltimoDiaMes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Depreciación Agregada");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Solo se permite depreciar el ultimo día del mes actual.");
        }
    }
```

Ya encontré solución a mi pregunta, les dejo el código para el futuro